# Python/OpenCV - How to keep the label of the objects moving in video and how to get the distance between them

Tags: python, opencv

Hellow guys, i'm doing a college project of a arduino robot arm that catch objects of a certain color using webcam with python/opencv.

The steps of my code are basically these:

1. Capture frame;
2. Convert frame BGR to HSV;
3. Threshold the HSV to get only the color i want;
4. Applying erode and dilate to the thresh
5. Find contours on the thresh using cv2.findContours
6. In a for loop get centroids of each contour detected using moments
7. Draw contours, a point(small circle) on the centroid with coordinates of the centroid (cx|cy), and write the object label(position of i on the loop) on the frame

Until here everything is smooth, but i ran into a problem, when i switch the position (especially the y axis) of the objects they switch the i position on the loop, what i want is that the algorithm know that "that object is the nº 1 even if he is above or below the object nº2 and nº3". I also want to know if there is a way to draw a line between the position of the object 0 (that is going to be the robot arm) and all the other objects, this way i get the position of the objects and i can move the robot to catch them.

Do you guys have any idea how i do this?
And sorry if there is any english mistake, i'm still learning english.

Here it goes the code i did so far and the prints of the code running.

```
# Importing libraries
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Creating callback function and Trackbars
def callback(x):
    pass
cv2.namedWindow('Trackbars', cv2.WINDOW_FREERATIO)
cv2.createTrackbar('LH', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('LS', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('LV', 'Trackbars', 0, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('UH', 'Trackbars', 255, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('US', 'Trackbars', 255, 255, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('UV', 'Trackbars', 255, 255, callback)

# Define a capture object and resizes to 640x360
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 360)

while True:
# Capturing the frame
    _, frame = cap.read()

# Converting to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Getting Trackbars value
    l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LH', 'Trackbars')
    l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LS', 'Trackbars')
    l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos('LV', 'Trackbars')
    u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos('UH', 'Trackbars')
    u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos('US', 'Trackbars')
    u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos('UV', 'Trackbars')

# Creating Lower and Upper arrays with the data of trackbars
    l_c = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    u_c = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

# Creating thresh
    thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, l_c, u_c)

# Applying Morphological transformations: Erosion and dilation on the thresh
    erode = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
    dilate = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE,(5,5))
    thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,erode,iterations = 2)
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,dilate,iterations = 2)

# Finding and drawing contours, centroid and centroid positions
    try:
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        for i, c in enumerate(contours):
            M = cv2.moments(c)
            cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
            cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
            cv2.drawContours(frame, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, "OBJECT "+(str(i)), (cx-35,cy-30),1,1,(0,0,255),1)
            cv2.circle(frame,(cx,cy),1,(0,0,255),2)
            cv2.putText(frame, str(cx)+","+ str(cy), (cx-35,cy+30),1,1,(0,0,255),1)
    except:
        pass

# Showing frame and thresh
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)

# 'Esc' key break the loop and destroy all windows
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

[Object 0, 1, 2, 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sF6k.png)

[Object 1 when goes up on the Y change position on the i of the for, turning to i = 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hldQw.png)

Thanks!